# Show only Checked Options using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, radio-button, checked

How to show only those options which are checked and hide all those which are not checked?

My code just shows checkbox, and not the label.

```js
$("#checked_show").click(function() {

  $("input").hide();
  $("label").hide();
  $("input:checked").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-1" value="2" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-1">Castle</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-2" value="3" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-2">Barn</label>

<br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="checkbox-3" value="5" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-3">Restaurant</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="checkbox-4" value="8" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-4">Bar</label>

<br /><br />

<button id="checked_show">Show only Checked</button>
```

How to show only those options which are checked and hide all those which are not checked?

My code just shows checkbox, and not the label.

Comment: Hint: `input:checked`

Comment: @Andreas, Apologies the question was incomplete. Now edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) to select the checked input and negate that with [`:not()`](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/), also to hide the labels you have to loop through all elements and select the next element using [`.next()`](https://api.jquery.com/next/), here is a working snippet:

```js
$("#checked_show").click(function () {
  if ($("input[type='checkbox']:checked").length) {
    $("input[type='checkbox']:not(:checked)").each(function (idx, el) {
      $(el).next().hide();
      $(el).hide();
    });
  } else {
    console.log('Please select an input!');
  }
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-1" value="2" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-1">Castle</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-2" value="3" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-2">Barn</label>

<br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="checkbox-3" value="5" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-3">Restaurant</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="checkbox-4" value="8" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-4">Bar</label>

<br /><br />

<button id="checked_show">Show only Checked</button>
```

Comment: Don't know why, when executing on my real code. It also hides the first `name` checked value. I am using the radio button so I edited the code as: `$("#my_form_id :input:not(:checked)").each(function(idx, el){` There are ten different question on my real code.

Comment: try to use `$("input[type='radio']:not(:checked)")` its should work, if you still face issues please add reproducible snippet or (jsfiddle)[https://jsfiddle.net/], that would help addressing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `input:checked` combined with `:not()` to select the inputs that aren't checked.

```js
$("#checked_show").click(function() {

  $("input:not(:checked)").each((i, el) => {
    $(el).next().hide();
    $(el).hide();
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-1" value="2" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-1">Castle</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="locationthemes" id="checkbox-2" value="3" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-2">Barn</label>

<br /><br />

<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="checkbox-3" value="5" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-3">Restaurant</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="location" id="checkbox-4" value="8" class="custom" />
<label for="checkbox-4">Bar</label>

<br /><br />

<button id="checked_show">Show only Checked</button>
```

Comment: Don't know why, when executing on my real code. It also hides the first `name` checked value. I am using the radio button so I edited the code as: `$("#my_form_id :input:not(:checked)").each(function(idx, el){` There are ten different question on my real code.